# Invoke file type action from Windows 7 command line

Tags: php, command-line, windows-7, file-type, file-association

Is there a way to invoke actions defined for a file type from the command line? I used FileTypesMan to define .phpcli for PHP CLI scripts and added actions run(php) and edit(netbeans). They both appear on the context menu and work as expected. But when working on the command line I can only invoke the default action via the .phpcli file itself. Is there a way to invoke the non-default action (in my case edit) from the command line?

Comment: In your specific example you could invoke the editor (netbeans), passing the name of the file as a parameter.

Comment: I know but actually it's more about usability sugar. I got several programs I could use for editing but each has its flaws and its benefits. Its just about not having to think about the editor every time I want to edit a file. I want to associate the best editor for every file type as an edit-action and invoke them in the exact same way. I know that this is kind of a luxury issue, but I want to have this as a way to make the system remember which is best for what. I've got more important things to think about than editor choices for different file types :)